# How to remove GPU prints in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use this code to use GPU in TensorFlow:

```
gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(gpus))

if gpus:
    tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
```

but when I execute this cell:

```
model=keras.Sequential([
    keras.Input(( X_train.shape[1],)),
    keras.layers.Dense(1024,activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    keras.layers.Dense(1024,activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    keras.layers.Dense(1024,activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    keras.layers.Dense(1024,activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(1),
])
model.compile(
    optimizer="adam",
    loss=correlation_coefficient_loss
)
```

The output is:

> Executing op VarHandleOp in device
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 Executing op
> AssignVariableOp in device
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 Executing op VarHandleOp
> in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 Executing op
> AssignVariableOp in device
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 Executing op VarHandleOp
> in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 Executing op
> AssignVariableOp in device
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 Executing op _EagerConst
> in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 Executing op
> RandomUniform in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
> Executing op Sub in device
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 Executing op Mul in
> device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 Executing op AddV2
> in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 Executing op
> VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
> Executing op AssignVariableOp in device
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 Executing op _EagerConst
> in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 Executing op
> Fill in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 Executing
> op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
> Executing op AssignVariableOp in device
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 Executing op _EagerConst
> in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0

This print is annoying.

**My question is, How to remove these GPU Prints of my output in TensorFlow?**

I try whit:

```
tf.autograph.set_verbosity(3)
```

but I was not successful

Comment: You asked tensorflow to print those messages, with your set_log_device_placement call.

Comment: Yes, Just remove the  tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True) line to stop incoming logs on Gpu usage.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to remove the debugging line **...and remember to restart your kernel!**

```
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
```